# Use Scipy to find a target value Python

Tags: python, scipy

I am new with scipy and python. I have searched quite extensively to find a tool similar to Excel Solver in Python and scipy seems to be very powerful. My question is kinda simple. I was trying to find the discount rate for a series of cash flows so that the sum of the present value of CFs equates to a specific value.

I got this error message if I run the codes. 1500 is my target value so I try to minimize the difference between my target value and f(DR).

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  DRfactor[i] = DRfactor[i-1]*(1+DRs[i])

Any and all help is much appreciated

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize


def f(DR):
    CFs = [100]*50
    DRs = [np.nan]*50
    DRfactor = [np.nan]*50
    for i in range(0,50):
        if 0<=i<=4:
            DRs[i] = DR
        else:
            DRs[i] = (DRs[i-1]-0.1)*0.9+0.1

        if i == 0:
            DRfactor[i] = 1+DRs[i]
        else:
            DRfactor[i] = DRfactor[i-1]*(1+DRs[i])

    CFPV = np.divide(CFs, DRfactor)
    CFsum = np.sum(CFPV)

    return (CFsum - 1500)**2

print (f(0.05))

sol = sp.optimize.minimize(f, 0.05)
sol.x
```

Comment: I am not yet sure why this is BUT your code works fine if you put a print just after the multiplication.

Comment: I ran this and printed out the values at the warning, and it gives `DRfactor[i-1]=[  2.51650823e+304]` and `DRs[i]=[  3.97637700e+11]`.  Seems like a problem with the algorithm.

Comment: Excel solver returns 0.0416111292046818 and I believe python can do better. probably I used a wrong scipy function?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. scipy.optimize.newton can zero out f(DR) and give 0.041611073570941355 which is the same answer given by excel solver.